# What's the origin of this quote from Plato? "To suffer the penalty of too much haste, which is too little speed"

Tags: plato, quote

Apparently the following quote belongs to Plato:

> To suffer the penalty of too much haste, which is too little speed.

However, unfortunately I couldn't find the context or origin (e.g. book, essay, etc.) of it. I was wondering if someone might know where that quote comes from.

Comment: I imagine that it is (as often in these cases) a quote found on the web (quora, etc.) without references. This means that it is copied and recopied and maybe it is not original, and means that it can be hard to find the original...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Actually, I found it in a mobile app for Philosophy quotes. And when I searched it on the web, there was only the quote without any reference to the origin of it. I'd really like to know and study the context of it, since it seems to me that there might have been some context around it; but it might be that I am wrong.

Comment: Or Doc Holliday, "Take your time in a hurry." Great minds think alike...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plato, [Statesman](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0172%3Atext%3DStat.%3Asection%3D264b), 264:

> **Stranger** Let us, then, not make our division as we did before, with a view to all, nor in a hurry, with the idea that we may thus reach political science quickly, for that has already brought upon us the proverbial penalty.

> **Younger Socrates** What penalty?

> **Stranger** The penalty of having made less speed, because we made too much haste and did not make our division right.